# Foundation & Isotope Transition Animaiton & Breakpoint Issues

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, jquery-isotope

I'm testing out a new Foundation-based page layout using Isotope. The transitions on my "isotope-item's" were working, however now they're not.

**I need help navigating where I went wrong with the CSS so I can re-enable the transition animations.**
And as an added bonus, why my first breakpoint doesn't force the 4 single-wide/tall boxes to the right, up underneath the four-wide/tall main box?

[LINK TO TEST DOMAIN](http://test.brandonmoner.me)

[LINK TO INSPIRATION](http://memphismusichalloffame.com)

[LINK TO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e5f85eo3/1/)

My current HTML code below (9/19/14):

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation 5.4.3 | Test Site</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/safe.css" />
  </head>
  <body class="split">
    <header class="left">
      <a class="brand brand-bg" title="This is a Demo Page" href="#"><img src="http://fs01.androidpit.info/a/c0/80/logo-me-c080cf-w192.png" alt="Logo"></a>
      <nav class="site-nav" id="navigation">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li class="browse "><a class="main-nav-item" href="#"><strong>LINK 1</strong> <span class="subhead">Sub-Head 1</span> <i class="ss-navigateright icon"></i></a></li>
          <li class="learn "><a class="main-nav-item" href="#"><strong>LINK 2</strong> <span class="subhead">Sub-Head 2</span> <i class="ss-navigateright icon"></i></a></li>
          <li class="discover "><a class="main-nav-item" href="#"><strong>LINK 3</strong> <span class="subhead">Sub-Head 3</span> <i class="ss-navigateright icon"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="grid home-grid isotope clearfix">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item four-wide four-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item triple-wide triple-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item double-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
        <div class="grid-cell isotope-item single-wide single-tall"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
    <script src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('.isotope').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
          transitionDuration: '0.8s',
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about a jsfiddle or link?

Comment: Sorry about that @Macsupport. I've updated my links in the main subject.

Comment: You test domain does not have isotope.js loaded

Comment: Macsupport. I'm checking it right now, and I do. Checking both the source and the resources tab in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED ANSWER

You are using isotope v2 which does not use css transitions so you need to remove the .isotope related transition css. You also do not have the .grid-sizer set in your css. Here is a working fiddle with transition duration set to 0.3 seconds. I will let you work on the css part. ;-)

The code is below.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/e5f85eo3/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.isotope').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
      transitionDuration: '0.3s',
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: I also do have the CSS. And I'm running v2.0.1. I'm I not seeing something that you are? I have my edits in a seperate CSS file called "safe.css"

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if there's an issue with the file heirarchy. Because once I switched SCRIPT positions of isotope and jquery...the animations are back but it's ignoring my grid CSS now.

Comment: jquery HAS to be loaded before isotope v1.5, it is required. Version 2 does not necessarily need jQuery ( see the site)

Comment: Ok Macsupport. So I've updated the code in my original post to display what my full index.html file contains currently on the test.brandonmoner.me site. As you can see, jQuery is being loaded before Isotope. And everything else seems to make logical sense hierarchy wise...so now I'm lost as to why these transition animations still aren't working.

Comment: Edited my original post along with link to altered jsFiddle based off of yours. If you go to test site...still not animating the transitions. And I made the changes you requested.

Comment: Updated it again. Animations are now happening, however the grid is busted again.

Comment: As I said, you need to set a width for grid-sizer! as an example: `.grid-sizer{width:20%;}`. Check out this updated fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/e5f85eo3/]

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance. Out of everything...that I did not even think of. Thank you. That definitely solves the issue. I'm marking your answer, however it seems that the reference sight is generating that dynamically with JavaScript...so more experimentation time for me :D